# mod_rewrite redirect to HTTPS redirects other rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a htaccess file like so

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule     ^search/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If I visit `http://example.com/search/abc123`, it redirects to `https://example.com/search.php?query=abc123`

The HTTPS redirect works like I want, but I don't like how it also redirects to `search.php?query=` instead of `search/`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [L]
```